# Probabilty of Drawing Specific Cards

Tags: probability, statistics, card-games

If I have a deck of randomized cards and I draw 5 cards, what is the probability that I will draw at least one 2 and at least one 3.  In other words, I am looking for any hands of the form x2xx3, 2x2x3, or x32xx (where x is any card), the order does not matter I just need at least one of each.  I know the probability of drawing at least one two is 1-(48!/43!)/(52!/47!) or ~0.0341158, and similarly for drawing at least one three, but what is the probability of drawing at least one of both.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You can use the fact that $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

Here, $P(A) =$ probability of drawing at least one two, $P(B) =$ probability of drawing at least one three, $P(A\cup B) =$ probability of drawing at least one two or at least one three, and $P(A\cap B) =$ probability of drawing at least one two and at least one three.

You say you know $P(A)$ and $P(B)$. Can you figure out $P(A \cup B)$?